# Executing Concatenation for all rows

Tags: linux, bash, genetics, gwas

I'm working with GWAS data.

Using `p-link` command I was able to get SNPslist, `SNPs.map`, `SNPs.ped`.

Here are the data files and commands I have for 2 SNPs (`rs6923761`, `rs7903146`):

```
$ cat SNPs.map 
0   rs6923761   0   0
0   rs7903146   0   0

$ cat SNPs.ped
6 6 0 0 2 2 G G C C
74 74 0 0 2 2 A G T C
421 421 0 0 2 2 A G T C
350 350 0 0 2 2 G G T T
302 302 0 0 2 2 G G C C
```

`bash` commands I used:

```
echo -n IID > SNPs.csv
cat SNPs.map | awk '{printf ",%s", $2}' >> SNPs.csv
echo >> SNPs.csv
cat SNPs.ped | awk '{printf "%s,%s%s,%s%s\n", $1, $7, $8, $9, $10}' >> SNPs.csv
cat SNPs.csv
```

Output:

```
IID,rs6923761,rs7903146
6,GG,CC
74,AG,TC
421,AG,TC
350,GG,TT
302,GG,CC
```

This is about 2 SNPs, so I can see manually their position so I added and called using the above command. But now I have 2000 SNPs IDs and their values. Need help with `bash` command which can parse over 2000 SNPs in the same way.

Comment: assuming the sample `SNPs.map` is what's in the `Camilleri.../...SNPs.map` file ... `cat Camilleri-SNPs/Camilleri-SNPs.map | awk '{printf ",%s", $2}'` generates `,0,0` (not `,rs6923761,rs7903146`); please update the question with the contents of `Camilleri-SNPs/Camilleri-SNPs.map`; also, what is the format of the `*.ped` file (alternatlivey, provide a sample from another `*.ped` file for 4x SNPs)

Comment: I have updated the file names, please check

Comment: I have tried this bash command

Comment: Need help with bash command which add every two alternative columns

'cat SNPs.ped | awk '{printf "%s,%s%s,%s%s\n", $1, $7, $8, $9, $10}' >> SNPs.csv`
like here above : "%s" extract $1 first column of ped file and then "%s%s" this adding two column values {$7,$8}, then {$9,$10}. Similarly I need to concat $1, {$7,$8}, {$9,$10}, {$11,$12}.....{1999,2000}

Comment: `cat SNPs.map | awk '{printf ",%s", $2}'` still generates `,0,0` so not sure how you were able to generate `,rs6923761,rs7903146` with the provided `SNPS.map` file

Comment: In the map file, the second column is the SNP id column. I'm not sure how it is extracting but that command working fine, can you help with command which add every two columns alternatively

Comment: please update the question with your additional details; formatting is lost in comments and in this case formatting is key to understanding how to parse the file(s)

Comment: you've now changed the format and content of `SNPs.map` ... completely different from before ... so ***NOW*** your code generates `,rs6923761,rs7903146`

Comment: The map file is like a space-delimited file, please check I have updated the details

Comment: Ya like that I have  2k SNPs i,e rs6923761, rs7903146, kgp22785968, kgp22786002..... Is there any way i can slicing or for loop which add every two columns alternatively starting from {$7&$8}, {9$&$10}.....till end

Answer (score 0):

One `awk` idea that replaces all of the current code:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { printf "IID" }

# process 1st file:

FNR==NR { printf ",%s", $2; next }

# process 2nd file:

FNR==1  { print "" }                       # terminate 1st line of output
        { printf $1                        # print 1st column
          for (i=7;i<=NF;i=i+2)            # loop through columns 7-NF, incrementing index +2 on each pass
              printf ",%s%s", $i, $(i+1)   # print (i)th and (i+1)th columns
          print ""                         # terminate line
        }
' SNPs.map SNPs.ped
```

**NOTE:** remove comments to declutter code

This generates:

```
IID,rs6923761,rs7903146
6,GG,CC
74,AG,TC
421,AG,TC
350,GG,TT
302,GG,CC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--recodeA` flag in `plink` to have your `IID` as rows and `SNPs` as columns.